# Getting Post Thumbnail to show for Single Post Obect (WP + ACF)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am having a hard time getting the Wordpress thumbnail to show up when I am using Advanced Custom Fields Pro Post Object.

My goal is to have the user select a single featured post to show up after the 6th post on the blog page.

This is my code (which is pretty much directly from ACF documentation):

```
<?php
$featured_post = get_field('featured_post', 'option');
if( $featured_post ): ?>

    <?php echo esc_html( $featured_post->post_title ); ?></h3>

    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

This returns the correct title but the wrong featured image (from the post above).

The code above is called inside the loop on index.php inside the featured template part.

```
$counter = 1;
                /* Start the Loop */
                while ( have_posts() ) :
                    the_post();

                /*
                 * Include the Post-Type-specific template for the content.
                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Type name) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'get_post_type()' );

                //check the counter and display your content
                if( $counter === 3 && !is_paged() ) { ?>
                    
                    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/components/component', 'subscribe'); ?>
                
                <?php } elseif ( $counter === 6 && !is_paged() ) { ?>
                    
                    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/components/component', 'featured'); ?>

                <?php }

                //update the counter on every loop
                $counter++;

            endwhile;
```

I have tried the other code examples on the documentation page but those return all of my posts (again with only one thumbnail, not the correct thumbnail per post).

I am not sure where to go from here.

Anyone who can help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since this is not in the loop context, the function does not find the correct post object set up to take the ID from. Use `get_the_post_thumbnail` instead, that takes the post id as parameter. (This function returns the image code, so you will have to explicitly `echo` it.)

Comment: @CBroe - Thanks, I just tried that but it still returns the wrong image. This is my code: `<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ); ?>`

Comment: Needs to be `$featured_post->ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is not in the loop context, the function does not find the correct post object set up to take the ID from. Use `get_the_post_thumbnail` instead, that takes the post id as parameter.

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $featured_post->ID ); ?>
```